# pandas assign across multiple columns functionally

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming, across

Is there a way, in pandas, to apply a function to some chosen columns, while **strictly keeping a functional pipeline** (no border effects,no assignation before the result, the result of the function only depends of its arguments, and I don't want to drop the other columns).
Ie, what is the equivalent of across in R ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
    "column_a":[0,3,4,2,1],
    "column_b":[1,2,4,5,18],
    "column_c":[2,4,25,25,26],
    "column_d":[2,4,-1,5,2],
    "column_e":[-1,-7,-8,-9,3]
    })
    .assign(column_a=lambda df:df["column_a"]+20)
    .assign(column_c=lambda df:df["column_c"]+20)
    .assign(column_e=lambda df:df["column_e"]/3)
    .assign(column_b=lambda df:df["column_b"]/3)
)
print(df)

# column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
# 0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
# 1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
# 2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
# 3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
# 4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

In R, I would have written :

```
library(dplyr)
df <-
tibble(
  column_a = c(0,3,4,2,1),
  column_b = c(1,2,4,5,18),
  column_c = c(2,4,25,25,26),
  column_d = c(2,4,-1,5,2),
  column_e = c(-1,-7,-8,-9,3)
) %>%
  mutate(across(c(column_a,column_c),~.x + 20),
         across(c(column_e,column_b),~.x / 3))

# # A tibble: 5 × 5
#   column_a column_b column_c column_d column_e
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1       20    0.333       22        2   -0.333
# 2       23    0.667       24        4   -2.33 
# 3       24    1.33        45       -1   -2.67 
# 4       22    1.67        45        5   -3    
# 5       21    6           46        2    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to unpack the computation within `assign`:

```py
(df
.assign(**df.loc(axis=1)[['column_a', 'column_c']].add(20), 
        **df.loc[:, ['column_e', 'column_b']].div(3))
)
   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

For readability purposes, I'd suggest splitting it up:

```py
first = df.loc(axis=1)[['column_a', 'column_c']].add(20)
second = df.loc[:, ['column_e', 'column_b']].div(3)
df.assign(**first, **second)

   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

Another option, still with the unpacking idea is to iterate through the columns, based on the pattern:

```py
mapper = {key : value.add(20) 
          if key.endswith(('a','c')) 
          else value.div(3) 
          if key.endswith(('e','b')) 
          else value 
          for key, value 
          in df.items()}

df.assign(**mapper)
   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

You can dump it into a function and then `pipe` it:

```py
def func(f):
    mapp = {}
    for key, value in f.items():
        if key in ('column_a', 'column_c'):
            value = value + 20
        elif key in ('column_e', 'column_b'):
            value = value / 3
        mapp[key] = value
    return f.assign(**mapp)

df.pipe(func)

   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

We can take the function declaration a step further for easier use :

```py
def across(df, columns, func):
    result = func(df.loc[:, columns])
    return df.assign(**result)

(df
.pipe(across, ['column_a', 'column_c'], lambda df: df + 20)
.pipe(across, ['column_e', 'column_b'], lambda df: df / 3)
) 
   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor) has a [transform_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.transform_columns.transform_columns) function that can be handy for this:

```py
(df
.transform_columns(['column_a', 'column_c'], lambda df: df + 20)
.transform_columns(['column_e', 'column_b'], lambda df: df / 3)
) 
   column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d  column_e
0        20  0.333333        22         2 -0.333333
1        23  0.666667        24         4 -2.333333
2        24  1.333333        45        -1 -2.666667
3        22  1.666667        45         5 -3.000000
4        21  6.000000        46         2  1.000000
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. These solutions are interesting, but these aren't really functional pipelines since you refer to the actual dataframe (which has hence to be assigned outside of the pipeline). Is there no possibilities to apply a *lambda* to multiple columns ? Thanks

Comment: you can always create a function instead; at any rate, you have to refer to the dataframe somehow - unless you want to use an anonymous function(lambda)

Comment: Yes, my goal is to only use anonymous functions, in a pure functional way. Is it possible it Python or are Python idiomatics not very mixable with pure functional programming ?

Comment: The point is that, I want one function to only depend of its arguments. Refering to an already assigned df somewhat break this chain.

Comment: `pipe` should help with that; easier to write out a function to handle it;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This isn't as readable as in R, but I guess it is the best way of doing it.